# Как поменять курсор в Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Есть программа tkinter. Нужно, чтобы в ней поменялся курсор (мыши,навсегда). Как это сделать? 
Код:

```py
from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime
root=Tk()
root.title('Stopwatch')

sec=0  #секунды
h=0   #минуты
after_id=''   #идентификатор возвращаемый методом after
def continue_sw():
    btn3.grid_forget()
    btn4.grid_forget()
    btn2.grid(row=1, columnspan=2, sticky='ew')
    tick()
def reset_sw():
    global sec,h
    sec=0
    h = 0
    btn3.grid_forget()
    btn4.grid_forget()
    btn1.grid(row=1, columnspan=2, sticky='ew')
    label1.configure(text='00:00')

def stop_sw():
    btn2.grid_forget()
    btn3.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='ew')
    btn4.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ew')
    root.after_cancel(after_id)#приостановка цикла

def tick():
    global sec,after_id,h
    after_id=root.after(1000,tick) #1000мс, tick-исполняемая функция
    if sec<60 and h<60:
        f_sec='%02d:%02d' % (h,sec)
        label1.configure(text=str(f_sec))
    elif sec==60 and h<60:
        h+=1;sec-=60
        f_sec = '%02d:%02d' % (h,sec)
        label1.configure(text=str(f_sec))
    else:
        stop_sw()
    sec += 1
def start_sw():
    btn1.grid_forget()
    btn2.grid(row=1,columnspan=2,sticky='ew')
    tick()



label1=Label(width=5,font=('Ubuntu',100),text='00:00')
label1.grid(row=0,columnspan=2)

btn1=Button(root,text='start', font=('Ubuntu',30),command=start_sw)
btn2=Button(root,text='stop', font=('Ubuntu',30),command=stop_sw)
btn3=Button(root,text='continiue', font=('Ubuntu',30),command=continue_sw)
btn4=Button(root,text='reset', font=('Ubuntu',30),command=reset_sw)


btn1.grid(row=1,columnspan=2,sticky='ew')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Какой вид курсора вам нужен и при каких событиях?

Comment: @mkkik При любых(While true , что бы навсегда поменялся)

Comment: `root.config(cursor=...)` [tkinter.cursors](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/cursors.html)

Comment: @mkkik Можно подробнее  , и в виде ответа,пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Глобальное изменение формы и цвета курсора для всей формы приложения можно задать в конфигурации главного окна.

```
from tkinter import Tk

root=Tk()
root.config(cursor='watch red') # красный watch-курсор
root.mainloop()
```

Также можно изменять курсор для отдельных виджетов, если у есть параметр `cursor`. Например:

```
tk.Button(root, text ="Button", cursor="heart")
```